# Why does calling "get-help entityframework" in the Package Manager Console cause this error?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, package-manager-console, nuget-cli

```
PM> get-help entityframework
```

> get-help : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + get-help entityframework
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Help], NullReferenceException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand

I guess it might be a problem related to PowerShell so I've listed its version number here

```
PM> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10586  494
```

And I'm using

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017
Version 15.8.7
```

Comment: You probaply mean `Get-Help about_EntityFrameworkCore` Get-Help is meticulous, but you can insert the `*` wildcard `Get-Help about_Entity*`

Comment: "get-help nuget" or other similar commands give me a similar errors

Comment: I presume that it supposed to work from any provider/location, but what happens when you change the location: [`Set-Location C:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-6)?

Comment: @iRon sorry but Set-Location is not relevant to this problem

Answer (score 5):

Once I installed the NuGet package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools, the error went away and i saw my list...

PM> get-help entityframework

```
                 _/\__
           ---==/    \\
     ___  ___   |.    \|\
    | __|| __|  |  )   \\\
    | _| | _|   \_/ |  //|\\
    |___||_|       /   \\\/\\
```

TOPIC
    about_EntityFrameworkCore

SHORT DESCRIPTION
    Provides information about the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools.

LONG DESCRIPTION
    This topic describes the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools. See https://docs.efproject.net for
    information on Entity Framework Core.

```
The following Entity Framework Core commands are available.

    Cmdlet                      Description
    --------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------
    Add-Migration               Adds a new migration.

    Drop-Database               Drops the database.

    Get-DbContext               Gets information about a DbContext type.

    Remove-Migration            Removes the last migration.

    Scaffold-DbContext          Scaffolds a DbContext and entity types for a database.

    Script-DbContext            Generates a SQL script from the current DbContext. 

    Script-Migration            Generates a SQL script from migrations.

    Update-Database             Updates the database to a specified migration.
```

SEE ALSO
    Add-Migration
    Drop-Database
    Get-DbContext
    Remove-Migration
    Scaffold-DbContext
    Script-DbContext
    Script-Migration
    Update-Database

Answer (score 2):

Install Entity Framework Tools first by using the below command.

`PM > Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

[image: Command line]

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently upgraded any related components? I ask because another user saw similar behaviour with NuGet after an MVC upgrade: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2192

Check that your NuGet and Entity Framework packages are up-to-date.

Are there any other strings for which get-help returns a similar error? If not, perhaps go so far as to uninstall and reinstall Entity Framework?

Comment: I checked and Nuget and Entity framework are up to date

Answer (score 0):

Installed the NuGet package -> **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools**

> help about_entityframeworkcore

```
                 _/\__
           ---==/    \\
     ___  ___   |.    \|\
    | __|| __|  |  )   \\\
    | _| | _|   \_/ |  //|\\
    |___||_|       /   \\\/\\
```

TOPIC
about_EntityFrameworkCore

SHORT DESCRIPTION
Provides information about the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools.

LONG DESCRIPTION
This topic describes the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools. See https://docs.efproject.net for
information on Entity Framework Core.

```
The following Entity Framework Core commands are available.

    Cmdlet                      Description
    --------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------
    Add-Migration               Adds a new migration.

    Drop-Database               Drops the database.

    Get-DbContext               Gets information about a DbContext type.

    Remove-Migration            Removes the last migration.

    Scaffold-DbContext          Scaffolds a DbContext and entity types for a database.

    Script-DbContext            Generates a SQL script from the current DbContext. 

    Script-Migration            Generates a SQL script from migrations.

    Update-Database             Updates the database to a specified migration.
```

SEE ALSO
Add-Migration
Drop-Database
Get-DbContext
Remove-Migration
Scaffold-DbContext
Script-DbContext
Script-Migration
Update-Database

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Check whether you have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package installed.
I guess you don't have, because I had the same problem when I did not have such package.

After installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
PM> get-help entityframework
Check it again, you will get the result you wanted)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was using VS2022 and in a solution with a lot of projects. My PM command was not working because my startup project WAS NOT the one with EF, my bad.
(doh)